# Replace lines in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with python to create a new frame starting from two frame by using Pandas.
The first frame (called frame1) is composed by the following line:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8   8
9   9   9   9   9
10  10  10  10  10
11  11  11  11  11
12  12  12  12  12
13  13  13  13  13
14  14  14  14  14
15  15  15  15  15
```

The second frame (called frame2) is:

```
A   B   C   D   E

19  19  19  19  19
24  24  24  24  24
29  29  29  29  29
34  34  34  34  34
39  39  39  39  39
44  44  44  44  44
49  49  49  49  49
54  54  54  54  54
59  59  59  59  59
64  64  64  64  64
69  69  69  69  69
74  74  74  74  74
79  79  79  79  79
84  84  84  84  84
89  89  89  89  89
94  94  94  94  94
99  99  99  99  99
```

Now i want to create a new dataset with this logic: starting from frame1 substitute every 5 row until the end of the frame1, the row of the frame1 with a random row of the frame2 (and remove the added row from frame2). A possible output should be:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4
59  59  59  59  59
6   6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8   8
9   9   9   9   9
29  29  29  29  29
11  11  11  11  11
12  12  12  12  12
13  13  13  13  13
14  14  14  14  14
84  84  84  84  84
```

How can i do this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
frame1.loc[4::5] = frame2.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

where

- `df.loc[4::5]` selects every fifth element, starting with the fifth one in `df`, and
- `df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)` shuffles a `df` around randomly

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works but it change also the first line (index = 0). How can i do to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to first obtain the indices where to update (we could also slice assign, but we'd have the problem of the `end` not being included), and then assign back taking a `sample` from `df2` of the corresponding size:

```
ix = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.arange(df.shape[0]+1)//5))
df1.iloc[ix] = df2.sample(df1.shape[0]//5).to_numpy()

print(df1)
     A   B   C   D   E
0    1   1   1   1   1
1    2   2   2   2   2
2    3   3   3   3   3
3    4   4   4   4   4
4   84  84  84  84  84
5    6   6   6   6   6
6    7   7   7   7   7
7    8   8   8   8   8
8    9   9   9   9   9
9   89  89  89  89  89
10  11  11  11  11  11
11  12  12  12  12  12
12  13  13  13  13  13
13  14  14  14  14  14
14  99  99  99  99  99
```

Comment: Thanks but I received the following error: ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'

Comment: @IvanVaccar I think If your `frame2` contains less number of samples than `frame1` then you might want to use `replace=True` but in that case the observations from `frame2` which are to be substituted in `frame1` will get repeated..

Comment: IIUC `df1.shape[0]//5` should be the size of `ix`, is it not? How do they differ in your real case? @IvanVaccari